# Trying to scrape post date from linkedin's board for first post and next ones

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, dom

I've DOM structure like here:

[image]

and trying to get xpath for text "2 dni temu".
How to dive into classes and find proper one. This is linkedin's board.

I was trying to start with:

```
//*[@class="occludable-update ember-view"][1]
```

Please help,
Jacek

Comment: Are you sure you want to get this element with selenium? This element appears hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `xpath`:

```
//div[contains(@class,'feed-shared-actor display-flex')]//span[@class='visually-hidden']
```

if you want 1st element:

```
feeds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'feed-shared-actor display-flex')]//span[@class='visually-hidden']")
print(feeds[0].text) # First element.
# Or
feeds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//main[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div")
# //main[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div[1] returns the 1st feed.
```

Comment: i tried also: //div[contains(@class,'feed-shared-actor display-flex')]//span[@class='visually-hidden'][1] and still the same

Comment: @JacekAntek -  Thats because `//div[contains(@class,'feed-shared-actor display-flex')]` points to all the feeds, in your case 22.

Comment: thank you so much. Can you teach me how to read this? I will pay

Comment: @JacekAntek -  I dint get you? You want to learn about finding xpath?

Comment: yes exactly i would like to scrap linkedin like a pro :)

Comment: @JacekAntek - Well, everything is in the internet now. Just a google search will give any tutorial. There are several websites to teach xpaths like [guru99](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) , [Javapoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/xpath-tutorial) and so on. And you can reach me at madhuc3633@gmail.com.